# Rails application not displaying index.html in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

I have placed an `index.html` file in the `public` directory of my Rails 4 application but it still shows this deleted file as rails welcome page. I am using Webrick in development mode. I have another app almost identical in setup which works fine.

Comment: make sure that you dont have a typo or a extra space in your file name or path.  that is most likely the problem

Comment: I have checked that carefully - doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: have you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, that in't the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written above, Rails 4 has removed the default index.html page in the /public folder. If you want to achieve the functionality anyway, you have to render the page manually. Just create a controller, and render the index page in your chosen controller action like this:

```
def index
  render :file => 'public/index.html' and return
end
```

EDIT:
If you want to serve the files without using the Rails stack, you have to configure your Web server (Apache/Nginx/whatever) to do so. Configurations for [Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309099/what-in-nginx-determines-what-goes-to-rails-and-what-is-served-directly) and [Apache](https://we.riseup.net/cgdev/apache-mongrel-rails#apache).
Additionally, you have to disable Rails' static file rendering in your configuration by setting `serve_static_assets` to false:

```
config.serve_static_assets configures Rails itself to serve static assets. Defaults
to true, but in the production environment is turned off as the server software (e.g.
Nginx or Apache) used to run the application should serve static assets instead.
Unlike the default setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!)
or testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won´t be able use
page caching and requests for files that exist regularly under the public directory
will anyway hit your Rails app.
```

So, if you want to use this in development mode, set `config.serve_static_assets` to false in `environments/development.rb`.

Comment: So, are you saying it's impossible to have a domain point to an index page without rendering it from a rails app if there is a rails app associated with the domain? If I type mydomain.com/index.html into a browser, I get a no route matches error message. Presumably this would be the same for every static page? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Looks like I didn't understand your question. Answer is now updated.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 uses dynamic index.html. Read on http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/dynamic-index-html-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: This does not solve my problem as I want to display my index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

Press F5 in navigator, the index can be in the cache.